# http header for downloading Microsoft Word and Excel files

Tags: php, html

I can download my microsoft word successfully if I named it in the filename by default. But if I use $variables to name it. The document extension will be unknown.

Sample:

```
$No = 1; 
$Name = 'John'; 
$Test = 'Science';

//Download header
$document->save($doc);
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/msword');
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='$No_$Name_$Test.docx");
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($doc));
ob_clean();
flush();
readfile($doc);
```

So if i rename my filename as variables. The file download will be without the docx extension. Anyone can advise?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change this

```
header('Content-Type: application/msword');
```

to

```
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
```

EDIT:

And change

```
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='$No_$Name_$Test.docx");
```

to

```
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"{$No}_{$Name}_{$Test}.docx\"");
```

Comment: I tried before already. Using firefox to save the document, it gives me no file extension which becomes unknown file.

Comment: invalid file too. I tried all ways but seems like IE and Firefox have this problem for me to download it successfully with file extension

Comment: Please correct you erroneous correction - the mime type of .docx files is application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document
 and the mime type of .xlsx files is application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet

Comment: @Parahat - http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee309278.aspx or http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsofficedeveloper/archive/2008/05/08/office-2007-open-xml-mime-types.aspx

Comment: finfo simply looks at the magic file to match a signature, and only recognises the PK heading in zipped files... it doesn't take the next step and look at the actual compressed content http://serverfault.com/questions/338087/making-libmagic-file-detect-docx-files . The official mime types are as I listed above, and those should be used in headers when downloading

Answer (score 21):

Correct headers are

for Excel (*.xlsx):

```
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="' . $fileName . '"');
```

for Word (*.docx):

```
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="' . $fileName . '"');
```

Comment: Why this complicated header instead of `application/zip` for Word ?

Comment: @MarceloRafael Why would you expect `application/zip` to work for a Word document?

Comment: Because it's basically a zip file

Comment: header("Content-Type : application/vnd.ms-excel") also works

Answer (score 2):

The correct use of that header is:

`Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="fname.ext"` note that if the name contains spaces it must be quoted

See [RFC6266](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6266) *section 5. Examples*