# Exported word doc gets saved as htm

Tags: php, header, ms-word, export

I'm using [html_to_doc](http://www.phpkode.com/source/s/html-to-doc-classes/html-to-doc-classes/html_to_doc.inc.php) to export html to .doc format which all works fine.
But the problem I'm having is that when I open the document and go to **Save As** the default document type is always **.htm / .html**.

I'm using Linux and I'd like to keep using this class if possible. These are the set headers in PHP:

```
@header("Cache-Control: ");// leave blank to avoid IE errors
@header("Pragma: ");// leave blank to avoid IE errors
@header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
@header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$this->docFile\"");
```

and the DOC header (without style):

```
<html xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml"
xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word"
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">

<head>
<meta http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<meta name=ProgId content=Word.Document>
<meta name=Generator content="Microsoft Word 9">
<meta name=Originator content="Microsoft Word 9">
<!--[if !mso]>
<style>
v\:* {behavior:url(#default#VML);}
o\:* {behavior:url(#default#VML);}
w\:* {behavior:url(#default#VML);}
.shape {behavior:url(#default#VML);}
</style>
<![endif]-->
<title>$this->title</title>
<!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>
<w:WordDocument>
<w:View>Print</w:View>
<w:DoNotHyphenateCaps/>
<w:PunctuationKerning/>
<w:DrawingGridHorizontalSpacing>9.35 pt</w:DrawingGridHorizontalSpacing>
<w:DrawingGridVerticalSpacing>9.35 pt</w:DrawingGridVerticalSpacing>
</w:WordDocument>
</xml><![endif]-->
<!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>
<o:shapedefaults v:ext="edit" spidmax="1032">
<o:colormenu v:ext="edit" strokecolor="none"/>
</o:shapedefaults></xml><![endif]--><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>
<o:shapelayout v:ext="edit">
<o:idmap v:ext="edit" data="1"/>
</o:shapelayout></xml><![endif]-->
$this->htmlHead
</head>
```

Comment: Whats in $this->docFile? Does that have a .doc/.docx extension

Comment: $this->docFile is the file that gets downloaded, which is just generated by the class

Comment: This will probably help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11487365/http-header-for-downloading-microsoft-word-and-excel-files

Comment: Not at all, if you look at my question you can see that I am able to download the file fine, but as soon as I open it and I choose 'save as ' then the filetype is set to html...

Comment: Well it isn't a BIFF format .doc file, or an OfficeOpenXML .docx file, and is basically just HTML markup - so perhaps that's why MS Word considers it as such

Comment: The html_to_doc is not creating a doc file... it's creating html markup that Word can read, and giving it a .doc extension