# File is empty when I'm trying to download a file using php

Tags: php

Well, I've a folder called `upload/doc` where all uploaded files are saved. After that I've a option to download uploaded files. So that I'm using following code:

```
<a target="_blank" href="upload_doc/<?php echo $rselectfile1['file_name']; ?>">Download</a>
```

It's download the file successfully but I don't want this so that I'm using another following code:

```
<a target="_blank" href="download.php?filename=<?php echo $rselectfile1['file_name']; ?>">Download</a>
```

**Download.php Code :**

```
<?php
@session_start();
//require_once("config.php");
if(!isset($_SESSION['front_username']) && isset($_SESSION['front_username']) == "" &&
    !isset($_SESSION['front_password']) && isset($_SESSION['front_password']) == "" &&
     !isset($_SESSION['user_id']) && isset($_SESSION['user_id']) == "") {
    header("Location:login.php");   
    exit();
}


$file_get = $_GET['filename'];

$tmp = explode(".",$file_get);
switch ($tmp[count($tmp)-1]) {
  case "pdf": $ctype="application/pdf"; break;
  case "exe": $ctype="application/octet-stream"; break;
  case "zip": $ctype="application/zip"; break;
  case "docx":
  case "doc": $ctype="application/msword"; break;
  case "csv":
  case "xls":
  case "xlsx": $ctype="application/vnd.ms-excel"; break;
  case "ppt": $ctype="application/vnd.ms-powerpoint"; break;
  case "gif": $ctype="image/gif"; break;
  case "png": $ctype="image/png"; break;
  case "jpeg":
  case "jpg": $ctype="image/jpg"; break;
  case "tif":
  case "tiff": $ctype="image/tiff"; break;
  case "psd": $ctype="image/psd"; break;
  case "bmp": $ctype="image/bmp"; break;
  case "ico": $ctype="image/vnd.microsoft.icon"; break;
  default: $ctype="application/force-download";
}

header("Pragma: public"); // required
header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Cache-Control: private",false); // required for certain browsers
header("Content-Type: $ctype");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$file_get."\";" );
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
header("Content-Length: ".$fsize);
ob_clean();
flush();
readfile("upload_doc/$file_get" );
?>
```

But in this way the downloaded file is **Empty** !! Do you know why it's empty and can you help me in fixing it ?

Thank You :)

Comment: You never set `$fsize`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change:

```
header("Content-Length: ".$fsize);
```

to:

```
header("Content-Length: ".filesize("upload_doc/$file_get"));
```

because you never set `$fsize`. The empty `Content-Length` header is being treated as a zero length, so you get an empty file.

Comment: Thanks Barmar I'm trying with this.

Comment: But still file is empty!

Comment: Strange! .doc and .docx file is empty now but .pdf and xls file is ok.

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11487365/http-header-for-downloading-microsoft-word-and-excel-files

Comment: I don't see any way that the file type could affect this.

Comment: He's saying it works for pdfs and xls, so it stands to reason the issue is the mime type header.

Comment: @Robbert AFAIK, the MIME type shouldn't affect the download process, although it may affect how the file is interpreted after it's downloaded, like giving it the wrong icon or not opening the correct application when you click on the file. But it shouldn't be empty.

Comment: @Shibbir Thanks for what? I haven't changed my answer since you said it didn't work for `.doc` and `.docx` files. Are you talking about Robbert's comment?

Comment: @Shibbir OK. I thought you said you tried it and it didn't work for `doc` and `docx` files.