# What should be the Content-type to open doc file uploaded by user in readable format in php?

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

What should be the Content-type to open doc file uploaded by user in readable format in php?

I have used the below format:

```
$headers1 .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=iso-8859-1" . "\n";
```

Here the file is not opening in a readable format.

Comment: Check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11487365/http-header-for-downloading-microsoft-word-and-excel-files

Answer (score 0):

You Can Try with this

```
<?php header('Content-type: application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text');?>
```