# How to create a download link with different users with Word in PHP

Tags: php, ms-word

I am newbie on PHP, I don't know how to handle this. So I have a different user then when they click on the link, it will automatically change inside the docx with their name and download.

So this what I've got so far, `str_replace(['[Recipient Name]'], ['My Name'], $word);`

but I only got the inside the Word, and the design is not there anymore.

so when the logged user visit this
`mysite.com/downloadCertificate`

it will pass his `name` then reedit the `.docx`, but what if there is many user download, it will always reedit the file? how to do just read the word then change the inside then create download link? how to do that?

for example: i have design like this

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dh7NW.png)

Comment: You should use this library https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord

Comment: Edit on the fly with php and then return the file with php.

Comment: can you give me flow how to do that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11487365/http-header-for-downloading-microsoft-word-and-excel-files 
If you try using something like this, but at the end instead of dumping the file, dump the file that you are editing, instead of saving it.

Comment: how to read the word first? with their layout, cause I only get text, not their align, size, bold/italic.